# Error 26 on SQL Server Express on local (non-networked) machine

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

An SQL server exception error 26 has occurred in a program that uses a local instance of SQL Server Express, on a machine that is stand-alone and not a part of any network. Anonymized screenshot is below. It's a legacy program that's been around for a long time and this is the first time (to my knowledge) that this exception has occurred.

Everything I've seen online about this error points to an attempt to access a remote machine, which of course is not the case here.

The connection string is `Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Initial Catalog=AppDb5_0;` This is set when the program starts and is never changed. To get to the point in the program where the exception occurred, the database would have been accessed many times, so it can't be a problem with the connection string.

EDIT: I do see this related question: [SQL Server: cannot connect from local website (SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14243595/468523). However, in that case it's related to the connection string, a problem that would have shown up almost immediately in my program.

What might have happened to cause this exception?

[image]

EDIT. Here's a zip of all the log files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyi8atc92e81hpv/SqlServerErrorLogs.zip?dl=0

EDIT

Here's one of the log files from the affected computer.

> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR)
>   (KB4293801) - 13.0.4223.10 (X64)
>
> Jul 26 2018 18:39:45
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>
> Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 17134: )
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      UTC adjustment: 10:00
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      All rights reserved.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Server process ID is 3888.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      System Manufacturer: 'MSI', System
>   Model: 'MS-7851'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Authentication mode is
>   WINDOWS-ONLY.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file
>   'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      The service account is 'NT
>   Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message; no user
>   action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Registry startup parameters:
>
> -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
>
> -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
>
> -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:18.22 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
>
> -s "SQLEXPRESS"
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:21.30 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with
>   2 cores per socket and 2 logical processors per socket, 2 total
>   logical processors; using 2 logical processors based on SQL Server
>   licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is
>   required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:21.30 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal
>   priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user
>   action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:21.30 Server      Detected 3972 MB of RAM. This is an
>   informational message; no user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:21.30 Server      Using conventional memory in the
>   memory manager.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:21.93 Server      Default collation:
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:23.00 Server      Buffer pool extension is already
>   disabled. No action is necessary.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:24.58 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid
>   failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:24.58 Server      Implied authentication manager
>   initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.37 Server      The maximum number of dedicated
>   administrator connections for this instance is '1'
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.38 Server      This instance of SQL Server last
>   reported using a process ID of 3900 at 8/22/2018 11:59:45 AM (local)
>   8/22/2018 1:59:45 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no
>   user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.41 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU
>   mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This
>   message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this
>   computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is
>   required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.44 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation. 
>   Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per
>   node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is
>   required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.47 Server      Database Instant File
>   Initialization: disabled. For security and performance considerations
>   see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server
>   Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is
>   required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:25.58 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:26.02 Server      Query Store settings initialized
>   with enabled = 1,
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.03 spid4s      Starting up database 'master'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.07 Server      Common language runtime (CLR)
>   functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.68 spid4s      SQL Server Audit is starting the
>   audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.69 spid4s      SQL Server Audit has started the
>   audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.83 spid4s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login
>   "sa".
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.84 spid4s      Server name is 'Lab-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.
>   This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.94 spid4s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:27.94 spid7s      Starting up database
>   'mssqlsystemresource'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.02 spid7s      The resource database build version
>   is 13.00.4223. This is an informational message only. No user action
>   is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.05 spid10s     A self-generated certificate was
>   successfully loaded for encryption.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.05 spid10s     Server local connection provider is
>   ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.06 spid10s     Server local connection provider is
>   ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.06 spid10s     Dedicated administrator connection
>   support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL
>   Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection,
>   restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational
>   message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.07 spid10s     SQL Server is now ready for client
>   connections. This is an informational message; no user action is
>   required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.07 Server      SQL Server is attempting to
>   register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service.
>   Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered
>   for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user
>   action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.08 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface
>   library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [
>   MSSQLSvc/Lab-PC:SQLEXPRESS ] for the SQL Server service. Windows
>   return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might
>   cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This
>   is an informational message. Further action is only required if
>   Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if
>   the SPN has not been manually registered.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.17 spid7s      Starting up database 'model'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.36 spid7s      Polybase feature disabled.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.37 spid7s      Clearing tempdb database.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.66 spid7s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.98 spid13s     The Service Broker endpoint is in
>   disabled or stopped state.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:28.98 spid13s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is
>   in disabled or stopped state.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:29.06 spid13s     Service Broker manager has started.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:29.11 spid4s      Recovery is complete. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:01:32.06 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
>
> 2018-08-22 12:36:42.09 spid51      Starting up database 'AppDb5_0'.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:05.09 Server      SQL Server is terminating because
>   of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user
>   action is required.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.48 spid13s     Service Broker manager has shut
>   down.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.48 spid13s     Error: 17054, Severity: 16, State:
>   1.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.48 spid13s     The current event was not reported
>   to the Windows Events log. Operating system error = (null). You may
>   need to clear the Windows Events log if it is full.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.50 spid4s      .NET Framework runtime has been
>   stopped.
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.57 spid4s      SQL Server shutdown has been
>   initiated
>
> 2018-08-22 14:38:06.57 spid4s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server
>   shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no
>   user action is required.

Comment: You ask, "What might have happened to cause this exception?" Stack Overflow can't troubleshoot for you. The error message is pointing you toward a problem. Have you started by doing research into that error message and possible causes?

Comment: Yes, of course. As I said in the post, everything I saw related to getting remote access working, which does not apply in this case. It's a one-off exception that I can't reproduce. I thought I made this clear in the post. I'm not asking Stack Overflow to troubleshoot for me. Just tell me if there's some reason this might occur in a stand-alone situation.

Comment: You do know there is a screenshot button on your keyboard, right? :) It's Left of the Scroll Lock  and Pause/Break keys, which are above the Insert, Home and Page Up keys

Comment: Of course. What's your point?

Comment: I'm guessing Larnu's point is that it would have been less effort than getting the picture from another device, and the quality of the image would have been much better. Still, it's better if error messages are written in the question as text rather than images, so that when other people search for that error in future, they find a match.

Comment: Ok. Odd comment thread since it has nothing to do with the problem I'm asking about ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What might have happened to cause [an intermittent connection faillure to a local instance]?

An intermittent connection failure to a local instance like this *strongly suggests* that the instance wasn't running when you tried to connect.  So check the SQL Logs.  They'll be in a folder like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLxx.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log
```

And will show all startup and shutdown events, in addition to failed logins.

Comment: A helpful response, thanks. I'll see if I can get that info.

Comment: While I'm waiting to see if I can get the log files from the user, why does an exception relating to remote database access suggest that the instance wasn't running? I tried to simulate the situation by pausing the service "SQL Server (SQL Express)" during the program execution and got the message "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): SQL Server service has been paused. No new connections will be allowed. To resume the service, use SQL Computer Manager or the Services application in Control Panel." So that's no help. It would be helpful if there were some way to force the problem.

Comment: I added code that let me shut down SQL Server just before the point where the problem occurred and got an error 26 exception with the same (misleading) message about remote connection. Now I know where to look for the underlying problem. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I see there was that `AppDb5_0` database startup was not until 30min after instance startup, and then the instance was stopped due to system shutdown.  When did the error occur?

Comment: I added a link to to the original post for all 7 errorlogs.

Comment: The 30 min is probably the time between PC startup and application startup. I don't know when the error occurred. I'll see if I can get a log of the error event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not been able to find out when the error occurred.